# Netsuite Advanced PDF/HTML reset variable's value for each page break

Tags: html, pdf, freemarker, netsuite

I want to make an advanced pdf/html template in Netsuite, I would like to print the sum value of the item quantities on the bottom of the table for each page of the template.

For Example:

```
    <table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
      <#assign sum=0/>
      <#list record.item as item>
        <#if item_index==0>
          <thead>
            <#assign sum=0/>
            <tr>
               <td>name</td>
               <td>quantity</td>
               <td>rate</td>
               <td>amount</td>
               <td>vat</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
             <td style="font-size: 10px;">${item.item}</td>
             <td style="font-size: 10px;">${item.description}</td>
             <td align="right" style="font-size: 10px;">${item.quantity}</td>
             <td align="right" style="font-size: 10px;">${item.rate}</td>
             <td align="right" style="font-size: 10px;">${item.amount}</td>
             <td align="right" style="font-size: 10px;">${item.taxrate1}</td>
          </tr>
        <#assign sum = sum + item.quantity/>
      </#list>
    </table>
```

[What I'd like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbmWa.png)

I want to print a sales order with something like 80 lines, I can't know how many line there may be for each page, so my idea (for the red value) was to assign the sum of the quantities to this variable "sum" inside the tag `<#list record.item as item></#list>` and reset its value for each page break but I don't know how to do that or if that's possible. Instead for the green value (which should show the previous page's red value) is a nice have and I have no idea how to do that, can someone please help me?

The language is freemarker, I have to use macros or functions?

Comment: Well, for one, you are resetting the sum variable at the start of each table to zero. `<#assign sum=0/>`. Each time this is generated, it will be generated with a new value of 0. I have no idea how to do this in APDF/HTML templates, I only use suitescript for generating forms and such, which might be a route that you choose to take if this is a feature that you have to have.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but I would start with this:

- declare `<#assign sum=0/>`above the footer macro definition.
- Emit sum in the footer macro
- reset `<#assign sum=0/>` in the footer macro after you emit it.
- make sure your macro definitions are at the top of the file before you sum any lines

  `<#assign somma=0 />
  <macro id="nlheader">...</macro>
  <macro id="nlfooter">
      <p style="color:red; font-size:28px;">${somma}</p> 
      <#assign somma=0/>
  </macro>`

Comment: `</macro>
         <#assign somma=0/>
            <macro id="nlfooter">
              <p style="color:red; font-size:28px;">
                ${somma}
              </p>`

Comment: You need to reset the sum inside the macro. and make sure you have `<#assign somma = somma + item.quantity/>` inside the item loop. (somma is not sum which was in your sample)

Comment: I'm so sorry but It doesn't work, I did exactly as you told me (now the variable is sum not somma): `<macrolist><#assign sum=0/><macro id="nlheader"></macro><macro id="nlfooter"><p style="color:red; font-size:28px;">${sum}</p><#assign sum=0/>other code</macro></macrolist>` and inside the loop: `<tr><#assign sum = sum + item.quantity/>other columns</tr>`. But the result is always 0

Comment: sorry it looks like the header and footer macros are only processed at definition. You can use variables within them but the variables are emitted with the values they had when the macros were created.

Comment: Ok, so in this way is not possible to do what I want. Can you please help me? Do you know some other solutions for my issue? It's very important for me. Thank you

Comment: Sorry. I don't know for sure of any way to do what you want. Next thing I'd try would be to use the <pbr> tag (see http://bfo.com/products/report/docs/userguide.pdf) or insert page breaks using CSS . For either of these you'd figure out approximately how many item rows fit on a page and just emit and then reset your total every X rows.